# Modify SPDEP package - insert new function

Tags: r, function, package, r-sp, spdep

I am trying to modify the stsls function of the R package spdep.
The function compute a spatial autoregressive function using a two stage least square. For both stages, the function uses the same spatial matrix.
What I want is to create a new function, say stslsm, which uses two different spatial matrices, one for the first stage (inlistw), one for the second stage (listw).

For this reason, I took the stsls function, I added a new entry, inlistw, and modified accordingly the script. For those who are interested, the code is at the bottom of this post, but please consider that this is just a first trial.

Now the problem is that I don't know how to insert this new function in the spdep package.
I read different posts on this issue. The most recurrent suggestion is:

```
unlockBinding("spdep", loadNamespace("spdep"));
assignInNamespace("stslsm", stslsm, ns=asNamespace("spdep"), envir=loadNamespace("spdep"));
assign("stslsm", stslsm, envir=env);
lockBinding(stslsm, loadNamespace("spdep"));
```

But after the second line of code I get the following

```
Error in bindingIsLocked(x, ns) : no binding for "stslsm"
```

I got stuck here. Do you have any suggestion?

```
function (formula, data = list(), listw, inlistw,zero.policy = NULL, 
      na.action = na.fail, robust = FALSE, HC = NULL, legacy = FALSE, 
      W2X = TRUE) {
if (!inherits(listw, "listw")) 
stop("No neighbourhood list")
if (is.null(zero.policy)) 
zero.policy <- get("zeroPolicy", envir = .spdepOptions)
stopifnot(is.logical(zero.policy))
if (class(formula) != "formula") 
formula <- as.formula(formula)
mt <- terms(formula, data = data)
mf <- lm(formula, data, na.action = na.action, method = "model.frame")
na.act <- attr(mf, "na.action")
if (!is.null(na.act)) {
subset <- !(1:length(listw$neighbours) %in% na.act)
listw <- subset(listw, subset, zero.policy = zero.policy)
}
y <- model.extract(mf, "response")
if (any(is.na(y))) 
stop("NAs in dependent variable")
X <- model.matrix(mt, mf)
if (any(is.na(X))) 
stop("NAs in independent variable")
if (robust) {
if (is.null(HC)) 
  HC <- "HC0"
if (!any(HC %in% c("HC0", "HC1"))) 
  stop("HC must be one of HC0, HC1")
}
Wy <- lag.listw(listw, y, zero.policy = zero.policy)
dim(Wy) <- c(nrow(X), 1)
colnames(Wy) <- c("Rho")
n <- NROW(X)
m <- NCOL(X)
xcolnames <- colnames(X)
K <- ifelse(xcolnames[1] == "(Intercept)", 2, 1)
 if (m > 1) {
 WX <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = (m - (K - 1)))
if (W2X) 
  WWX <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = ncol(WX))
for (k in K:m) {
  wx <- lag.listw(inlistw, X[, k], zero.policy = zero.policy)
  if (W2X) 
    wwx <- lag.listw(inlistw, wx, zero.policy = zero.policy)
  if (any(is.na(wx))) 
    stop("NAs in lagged independent variable")
  WX[, (k - (K - 1))] <- wx
  if (W2X) 
    WWX[, (k - (K - 1))] <- wwx
}
if (W2X) 
  inst <- cbind(WX, WWX)
 else inst <- WX
}
if (K == 2 && listw$style != "W") {
wx1 <- as.double(rep(1, n))
wx <- lag.listw(inlistw, wx1, zero.policy = zero.policy)
if (W2X) 
  wwx <- lag.listw(inlistw, wx, zero.policy = zero.policy)
if (m > 1) {
  inst <- cbind(wx, inst)
  if (W2X) 
    inst <- cbind(wwx, inst)
}
else {
  inst <- matrix(wx, nrow = n, ncol = 1)
  if (W2X) 
    inst <- cbind(inst, wwx)
}
}
result <- tsls(y = y, yend = Wy, X = X, Zinst = inst, robust = robust, 
             HC = HC, legacy = legacy)
result$zero.policy <- zero.policy
result$robust <- robust
if (robust) 
result$HC <- HC
result$legacy <- legacy
result$listw_style <- listw$style
result$call <- match.call()
class(result) <- "stsls"
result
}
```

Comment: Why would you do this? If you think this is an addition to `spdep` that is also useful to others, submit the function (with documentation, tests and examples) to the package maintainer, and ask him to include it in the next release. It this is only for your personal use, you can keep the function in your global environment, or in a private package.

Comment: Hi Edzer, if I run the function in the global environment I get this error 
`Error in get("zeroPolicy", envir = .spdepOptions) :   object '.spdepOptions' not found`. On a mailing list archive, I've found the developer of the package discussing this error. He said "the reasons functions and variables are not found in your case is that they are not exported in the NAMESPACE, so need to be prepended with
spdep:::. ". Now if I run `spdep:::.` I get `Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : object '.stslsm' not found`. This is why I want to insert the function in the package